# Proper way to do one-way serialization

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Say I have a class like this:

```
public class AlphaBravoRatio
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}
    public double Ratio { get { return A * 1.0 / B; } }
}
```

Is there a way to decorate this class such that Ratio gets serialized but not deserialized?

It works with this implementation but I'm wondering if it can be done without the empty setter.

```
public class AlphaBravoRatio
{
    public int A {get; set;}
    public int B {get; set;}
    public double Ratio 
    { 
        get { return A * 1.0 / B; } 
        set {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the ratio to be serialized then if you are not going to deserialize (and thus, get the value) back?

Comment: Well, consumer will have a data class generated automatically (if "Add Service Reference..." used) which will not contain calculation logic inside. Otherwise I assume you are giving your class to the consumer to have the same data classes from your library as you have. EDIT: ah sorry, you mean non-WCF serialization.

Comment: They can do whatever they want with the XML.  My service is just broadcasting it; it does not share code and does not care _what_ they do with it.  It's just providing the information as _it_ is perceiving it to be.

Comment: I dont think you can with the XML serializer, by "think" I mean, I've never found a way, and I've done what you already suggest. You could ofc write you own serializer but I doubt that its worth it.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) and only implement the WriteXml method.